# create one css template that cover the whole of tha page without margin and even if the comtent is almost empty

Tags: html, css, templates

I created one template and I want the top menu is at the top of the page and take a whole of the width of the page and after

I want the left menu and center take the whole of the page

and the footer has the same caracteristics of the top menu

and if the content of the left-menu or the center is small : the whole of the page is cover by the center and left-menu  with the footer on the bottom without scrollbar

this is what I tried : [click me :)](http://jsfiddle.net/cQMur/4/)

```
   #page{
    background-color : black;    
}
#top-menu{
    background-color : yellow;
}
#left-menu{
    background-color : blue;
    float:left;
}
#center{
    background-color : red;
}
#footer{
    background-color : green;
}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using percentages for height and width you can achieve the effect you want:

```
html, body, .page {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.top-menu{
    background: yellow;
    height: 15%;
}
.left-menu{
    background: blue;
    float:left;
    height: 75%;
}
.center{
    background: red;
    height: 75%;
}
.footer{
    height: 10%;
    background: green;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQMur/5/)

**EDIT:** Based on your comments, here is an updated solution:

One option is to set a `min-height` on `.center` as a percentage.

Sidebars with equal height is not easy or intuitive to solve with CSS. Using a technique called ['faux columns'](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) which consists of having a background image for `.content` rather than a background for `.left-menu` directly, you can achieve the effect. I used CSS3 gradients (with SCSS with Compass in the Pen to make this easier, but you can do all the browser prefixing manually).

Updated CSS:

```
html, body, .page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-menu {
  background: yellow;
  height: 15%;
}

.left-menu {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.center {
  background: red;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 50%, 100% 50%, color-stop(0%, #0000ff), color-stop(25%, #0000ff), color-stop(25%, #ff0000));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0000ff, #0000ff 25%, #ff0000 25%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #0000ff, #0000ff 25%, #ff0000 25%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #0000ff, #0000ff 25%, #ff0000 25%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #0000ff, #0000ff 25%, #ff0000 25%);
  min-height: 75%;
  padding-left: 26%;
}

.footer {
  height: 10%;
  background: green;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/souwD)

Comment: thank you :), it works, but when the content of the center is big (need more than the height of the page) it doesn't work

Comment: What do you want to happen when the content is larger than the space in the browser? Depending on what effect you want, add `overflow: scroll` or set a `min-height` on `.center`.

Comment: I tested min-height, it works but the height of the left-menu doesnt' change and the center take the whole of height of the page

Comment: Then set a `min-height` on the `.left-menu` as well!

Comment: I want : when the center of left-menu contains a lot of content the height of both changes

Comment: min-height doesn't resolve the problem even if I put it for both

Comment: [Equal height columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) are not easy in CSS, unfortunately. Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve my problem here is the trick  :  adding this jquery code  :

```
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('#left-menu').height($('#center').height());
});
</script>
```

after my html code :

```
    <div id="page" >
    <div id="top-menu" >
        content of top menu
    </div>
    <div id="left-menu" >
        content of left menu
    </div>
    <div id="center" >

<p>content of center</p><p>content of center</p><p>content of center</p><p>content of center</p><p>content of center</p>

 </div>
    <div id="footer" >
        content of footer
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css :

```
    html, body, #page {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#top-menu{
    background: yellow;
    height: 6%;
}
#left-menu{
    background: blue;
    float:left;
    min-height: 90%;
    min-width: 15%;
}
#center{
    background: brown;
    min-height: 90%;

}
#footer{
    clear : both;
    height: 4%;
    background: green;
}
p{
margin : 0;
}
```

@bookcasey thank you for the helping hand  ;)